# Salesforce opportunity stages

Tags: apex, soql, rest-api, opportunity, standard-objects

Is that possible to get the stage name, probability and forecast category using SOQL/Apex/APIs ? and I could not find that you can pull that data.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out the **[`OpportunityStage`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_opportunitystage.htm)** object.

```
SELECT
    MasterLabel,
    DefaultProbability,
    ForecastCategory,
    IsClosed,
    IsWon
FROM OpportunityStage
```

Comment: Thank you and I don't know why I did not look `OpportunityStage` :)

Comment: @NickKahn Side note, there's also similar objects for Lead Status and Case Status, in case you ever need those.